# Tikz, Save common parameters into variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have to draw multiple node like this :

```
\node[circle, minimum size=2cm] (P0) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node[circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=red] (P1) at (1,0) {$2$};
\node[circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=black] (P2) at (2,0) {$3$};
```

But each time i have circle and minimum size in common, i try to do something like that :

```
\newcommand{\NodeClassic}{circle, minimum size=2cm}
\newcommand{\NodeRed}{circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=red}
\newcommand{\NodeBlack}{circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=black}
```

And after :

```
\node[\NodeClassic] (P0) at (0,0) {$1$};
\node[\NodeRed] (P1) at (1,0) {$2$};
\node[\NodeBlack] (P2) at (2,0) {$3$};
```

Like this, i can add some parameters :

```
\node[\NodeClassic, yellow] (P0) at (0,0) {$1$};
```

My document :

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\NodeClassic}{circle, minimum size=2cm}
\newcommand{\NodeRed}{circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=red}
\newcommand{\NodeBlack}{circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[\NodeClassic] (P0) at (0,0) {$1$};
    \node[\NodeRed] (P1) at (1,0) {$2$};
    \node[\NodeBlack] (P2) at (2,0) {$3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Error message on Overleaf :

```
 Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=red' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16     \node[\NodeRed]
                         (P1) at (1,0) {$2$};
```

I have already try \def\command{params} or \tikz{params} inside \newcommand
Thank you,

Comment: There is no expansion in option, so that will not work. Use styles...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use styles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  NodeClassic/.style={draw,circle, minimum size=2cm},
  NodeRed/.style={circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=red},
  NodeBlack/.style={circle, minimum size=2cm, fill=black!20},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[NodeClassic] (P0) at (0,0) {$1$};
    \node[NodeRed] (P1) at (2,0) {$2$};
    \node[NodeBlack] (P2) at (4,0) {$3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I changed the options to draw the white circle and to have less black in the black node, just in order to see the node contents.

[image]

There is no `14pt` option for `article`.

Answer (score 8):

The variables you are looking for are called 'styles'. The styles can also have parameters. As an example,

```
  mynode/.style={circle,minimum size=2cm,fill=#1},
  mynode/.default={white}
```

defines a style `mynode` with one parameter, the fill color. Its default value is `white`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mynode/.style={circle,minimum size=2cm,fill=#1},
  mynode/.default={white}
  ]
  \node[mynode] (P0) at (0,0) {$1$};
  \node[mynode=red] (P1) at (1,0) {$2$};
  \node[mynode=black] (P2) at (2,0) {$3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```